# Timezone in angularjs is not correct in ie9 document mode

Tags: javascript, date, angularjs, datetime, timezone

I am retrieving a datetime from my server as this:

```
"created":"2013-07-22T22:00:48.860"
```

In my html i am using this angular statement:

```
{{createdDateTimeShortString(currentEvent.created) | date:'M/d H:mm'}}
```

and in my controller i have this function:

```
  $scope.createdDateTimeShortString = function (date) {
        if (!date) {
            return false;
        }
        var dtime = new Date(date);
        return dtime;
    };
```

This works exactly as i would expect in chrome, firefox and ie10.
But when i switch to IE9 Document Mode then all of my dates lose 4 hours.
Only a change in Document Mode does this. If i'm in IE9 Browser Mode but Standards document mode then i get the expected time.

How can this be and is there a way to fix this so it works in all browsers/modes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your dates are in [ISO8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format, which is good.  There are multiple variations of this format though.

When you specify your input as `2013-07-22T22:00:48.860`, the time zone is not part of the data, so it is open for interpretation.  Some browsers may see this as UTC, some may consider it to be the local time of the computer it's running on.

Instead, you should be specific.  If your times are in UTC, then add a `Z` at the end of your string, such as `2013-07-22T22:00:48.860Z`.

If your times are in a particular time zone, then you should provide the corresponding time zone offset that is in effect at that time.  For example, if your times are in the US Eastern time zone, then ***at this time*** it would be 4 hours behind UTC, so you would specify that as `2013-07-22T22:00:48.860-04:00`.

Comment: good suggestion, thank you. what if i have no control over the server portion, but i know that the time is UTC. how would i overcome this issue with only client side code?

Comment: You could try adding a `Z` at the end of the string when it's originally being parsed in your JavaScript code.

Comment: You might also consider using [moment.js](http://momentjs.com).  With that, you can say `moment(yourLocalDate)`, or `moment.utc(yourUtcDate)`

Comment: tacking the Z on seemed to work - it got IE9 to give dates consistent with the other browsers. I think the issue now is that all of my dates are shifted 4 hours from what i think they should be. and thank you for your assistance.

Comment: Instead of tacking on the "Z" i instead tacked on "-04:00" and all is well. thank you kindly.

Comment: Careful with that.  If the time zone you are working with has daylight saving time, then it might not always be the same offset.  For example, if these are US Eastern Time values, then -4 is only valid until DST ends on November 3rd and then it is back to the standard offset of -5.  If you are going to tack on an offset, it really should be coming from your server.

Comment: unfortunately, i'm still struggling with this. I am trying to use moment.js but it keeps returning my date with quotes around it like a string and that looks terrible in my app. i tried mDate = moment(d) and i also tried mDate = moment(d).toDate()

Comment: try `moment(d).toISOString()` or `moment(d).utc().format()`.  But again, make sure you know if the data from your server is UTC or something else.  You don't want to be guessing.  And not really sure what you mean about the quotes.  Perhaps you should ask a new question and show exactly what you're doing now.